# How do I get React Router DOM to work from a CDN link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, cdn

I want to use React Router DOM using this [CDN](https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.6.1/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js).

In my App.jsx file, I have the following:

```
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const BrowserRouter = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;

...

<div>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="row mt-3">
            <div className="col-2">
            {folders.map((x, folderId) => { return (
                <div key={folderId}>
                    <Link to={`folder/${x.name}`}>{x.name}</Link>
                </div>
                ); })}
            </div>
            <div className="col-2"></div>
            <div className="col-8"></div>
        </div>

        <Route path="/folder/:name" element={<Folder/>}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

When rendering, I get the error:

> index.tsx:1219 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Route')

Is there something I forgot to import? Am I using the wrong React Router DOM version? Thanks in advance

Comment: add this to html head `<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.6.1/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>` should work